# Is critical damping same as resonance condition?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

Because frequency of external force is equal to that of the natural frequency of oscillator...can we call it resonance condition...if yes or no why?
If no,then when do we get resonance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, "critical damping" is NOT the same as "resonance condition". Critical damping is that specific condition where the amount of resistance in a resonant system is just right to produce the quickest possible dissipation of the initial energy stored in it. In fact, it prevents oscillation by causing the dissipation to go to completion before cycles of oscillation have an opportunity to get established.

Resonance condition is when the driving frequency matches the natural frequency of oscillation of a system, and the amplitude of the oscillations grows to a peak.